# Different Anova results from the same comparisons

Tags: r, anova

I have to two matrices (`d1, d2`) that represent data from two different experiments where rows are different measurements and columns are different timepoints (3 replicates per timepoint).

I want for every measurement on each timepoint to run Anova between the two experiments and record their p-values. All measurements (rows) for my first timepoint equal 1, across the 3 replicates for both experiments. I meant to exclude this timepoint from my code, but I forgot to do so and I found out that Anova returns different results despite their constant values (`Output[1,]`). So that got me questioning my method. Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong with my code?

Dummy Sample of my data and code follow below:

```
expA <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
'expA.1 expA.1 expA.1    expA.2    expA.2    expA.2    expA.3    expA.3    expA.3
1      1      1      1 1.0590361 6.0840000 0.3126238 0.9512048 0.5080000 0.1923839
2      1      1      1 1.0250958 2.2046729 1.0730671 1.1411717 1.8937081 0.8498161
3      1      1      1 0.5253539 0.7999517 0.5635622 0.5484518 0.5883386 0.8645538
4      1      1      1 1.2129670 1.4956726 1.5498014 1.7048222 1.1656466 1.6938889
5      1      1      1 0.1903024 3.6452976 0.8402939 0.7885819 2.6368440 0.9033027
6      1      1      1 0.9538349 1.9105057 1.3856549 1.0811355 1.5250233 1.3113107')

expB <- read.table(header = TRUE, text =
'expB.1 expB.1 expB.1    expB.2    expB.2    expB.2    expB.3    expB.3    expB.3
1      1      1      1 0.5850559 0.5858956 0.4498688 0.7030726 0.5139633 0.4788714
2      1      1      1 0.8810560 0.9518831 1.2129251 0.9662685 1.1690522 1.1529898
3      1      1      1 0.8331984 0.7367421 0.7101967 0.9298349 1.0121873 0.8389997
4      1      1      1 0.9780624 0.7264760 1.1186710 0.7796886 0.6307443 1.0288995
5      1      1      1 0.6441718 1.2217535 0.7014686 1.1087473 1.3889726 0.7439220
6      1      1      1 1.1069592 1.3709256 1.3999807 1.3019256 1.3422111 1.5893162')

#Anova loop code
    Output <- array(numeric(0), c(6, 3))
    for (i in 1:nrow(expA)) {
        Output[i,] <- c(unlist(summary(aov(c(t(expA[i,1:3]), t(expB[i,1:3])) ~ c(rep("expA", 3), rep("expB", 3)))))[9],
                       unlist(summary(aov(c(t(expA[i,4:6]), t(expB[i,4:6])) ~ c(rep("expA", 3), rep("expB", 3)))))[9],
                       unlist(summary(aov(c(t(expA[i,7:9]), t(expB[i,7:9])) ~ c(rep("expA", 3), rep("expB", 3)))))[9]
                       )
                       #unlist(summary(aov(c(t(expA[i,10:12]) 
}

#Output table of p-values
         t.1          t.2        t.3
1 0.4158234414 0.34373556 0.95204240
2 0.0328117398 0.35232074 0.56545725
3 0.0006251536 0.23615864 0.07974182
4 0.6730575455 0.03679283 0.02900738
5 0.5410373240 0.54923102 0.59392961
6 0.0050755052 0.69271985 0.53786311
```

Comment: I get the same value in t.1

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The plot was actually thicker as the anova works for the subset but not for the original dataset. And the reason is that in the original dataset, the first three columns (represented by 1s), are stored as numerical values while in the subset, as integers.